# Checking if a external 3rd party site exists

Tags: jquery, input

Users are able to enter a URL into a text field, I would like to add a jQuery based feature that would be able to check if a page at least exists so that I could warn a user if they may have accidentally entered an incorrect URL, before they hit "save"

Currently I am trying to use the following code, though it seems to always return the "Error: Does not exist" message:

```
$('#Inventory_edocsUrl').blur(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:$('#Inventory_edocsUrl').val(),
        type:'GET',
        success: function()
        {
            console.log('Success, file exists!');
        },
        error: function()
        {
            console.log('ERROR:Does not exist');
        }
    });
});
```

I tested with `http://google.com` as a test url in the text field and it still returned the error. Upon switching the url to `google.com` (not http), I got the same error message along with another error message:

```
GET http://localhost/inventory/web/inventory/google.com 404 (Not Found)
```

It makes sense that this second version does not work as there is no http:// and therefore the error should be returned, but I don't see why the first correct url is returning the programmed error message, but is actually returning no console errors like the second trial.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Lix no, these ones are a little different.

Comment: You wanna test if a URL exists, no? How is it different?

Comment: @Lix I'm trying to find out what is wrong with what I am specifically doing.

Comment: @Lix most of the other solutions I am finding do not seem to work with external URL's.

Comment: That's the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You need a proxy on your server.

Comment: @Juhana So, does it work as long as they are on the same domain? Because as of right now I only need to check if documentation URL's are correct, which are on a totally different server here, but still are accessed from the same domain, just a different directory.

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: @Juhana Well, technically you answered my question of what was wrong, so feel free to make this an answer and I will accept that.

Comment: I can't answer a question that's closed, but it's a duplicate anyway.

Comment: @Juhana ah oh well, it wasn't marked as a duplicate before this.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate at all !

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert("page not found");
        }
    }
});
```

Form jQuery.ajax() documentation....

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
url:$('#Inventory_edocsUrl').text();
```

Instead of:

```
url:$('#Inventory_edocsUrl').val();
```

Comment: *"Users are able to enter a URL into a **text field**"* --> `.val()` is correct.

Comment: No, this is a text field, I know the value is being retrieved correctly.